# same height of multiple li in javascript

Tags: javascript, height

i am new in javascript. its working fine if we refresh the page but its not working when we resize the window.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    equl_height();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    equl_height();
}); 


function equl_height () {
    var highestBox = 0;
    $('ul li').each(function(){  
        if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
            highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('ul li').height(highestBox);
}
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net? or put a console log in the `equl_height` method to check if the method is executed or not?

Answer (score 0):

`window.addEventListener("resize", equl_heigh);`

cheers!

Comment: Why have you put "equl_heigh" as a string? And why would addEventListener work if the jquery code didn't?

Comment: hello jimish
its not working
 $(window).load(function(){
equl_height();
});
   

 
window.addEventListener("resize", "equl_height");
 function equl_height () {
      var highestBox = 0;

        $('ul li').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('ul li').height(highestBox);
    }

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
         equl_height(); 
     });
   

  $(window).resize(function(){
          equl_height();
      });
   
window.addEventListener("resize", equl_height);
 function equl_height () {
      var highestBox = 0;

        $('ul li').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('ul li').height(highestBox);
    }
still its not working
plz help

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in how you measure height of an `li`. use `scrollHeight` instead of `height()`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/g99nwq49/).

Update your `equl_height` method with

```
function equl_height () {
    console.log( "resizing" );
    var highestBox = 0;
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        //var height = $(this).outerHeight();
        var height = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
        if(height > highestBox){  
            highestBox = height;  
        }
    });    
    $('ul li').outerHeight(highestBox);
}
```

Also, since resize event can be fired at a higher rate so try this [throttling trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#requestAnimationFrame_customEvent) as well.

Comment: *"do not override the window.onresize function"* - the code (currently) shown in the question doesn't use onresize, it uses the relevant jquery method.